# Placing .desktop file

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

Trying to add eclipse_java.desktop file on my Ubuntu 20 desktop with content below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse Java
Icon=/home/a/eclipse/eclipse_java/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/a/eclipse/eclipse_java/eclipse
```

Unfortunately it does not changes to icon. File attribute:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 a a  174 Nov 18 09:19 eclipse_java.desktop
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the eclipse_java.desktop file that is located on your ~/Desktop, and select **Allow Launching**. Assuming that your Icon and Exec lines are correct, the icon should flip immediately.